# Can't install pdftotext

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pdftotext

I've been trying, without any luck, to install `pdftotext` module (Python), but it fails, and returns a bunch of errors. So, you guys could help me figure it out, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pdftotext
Collecting pdftotext
  Using cached pdftotext-2.1.5.tar.gz (98 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pdftotext
  Building wheel for pdftotext (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\humma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\humma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\humma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2qhv15mt'
       cwd: C:\Users\humma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\pdftotext\
  Complete output (69 lines):
  WARNING: pkg-config not found--guessing at poppler version.
           If the build fails, install pkg-config and try again.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pdftotext' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=1 -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tppdftotext.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pdftotext.obj -Wall
  pdftotext.cpp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(49): warning C4820: '_finddata32i64_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_finddata32i64_t::name'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(54): warning C4820: '_finddata64i32_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_finddata64i32_t::attrib'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(64): warning C4820: '__finddata64_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '__finddata64_t::attrib'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(69): warning C4820: '__finddata64_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '__finddata64_t::name'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\time.h(36): warning C4820: '_timespec64': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_timespec64::tv_nsec'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\time.h(43): warning C4820: 'timespec': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'timespec::tv_nsec'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\object.h(182): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::slot'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\object.h(190): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::flags'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(212): warning C4820: '_typeobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_typeobject::tp_flags'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(256): warning C4820: '_typeobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_typeobject::tp_version_tag'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\bytearrayobject.h(30): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ob_exports'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\bytesobject.h(41): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ob_sval'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\bytesobject.h(165): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::small_buffer'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(221): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::state'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(625): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '2' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::readonly'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\longintrepr.h(88): warning C4820: '_longobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_longobject::ob_digit'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\memoryobject.h(45): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::flags'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\memoryobject.h(62): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::flags'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\methodobject.h(56): warning C4820: 'PyMethodDef': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'PyMethodDef::ml_flags'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\moduleobject.h(63): warning C4820: 'PyModuleDef_Slot': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'PyModuleDef_Slot::slot'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(16): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::_type'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(19): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::exitcode'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(202): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::parse_argv'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(357): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::legacy_windows_stdio'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(367): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::pathconfig_warnings'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(374): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::module_search_paths_set'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(393): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::skip_source_first_line'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(65): warning C4820: '_ts': '2' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::recursion_critical'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(73): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::use_tracing'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(96): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::gilstate_counter'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(130): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::coroutine_origin_tracking_depth'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(35): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::gi_running'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(55): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::cr_running'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(72): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ag_running'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(85): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ag_running_async'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\descrobject.h(29): warning C4820: 'wrapperbase': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'wrapperbase::offset'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\descrobject.h(33): warning C4820: 'wrapperbase': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'wrapperbase::flags'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\structseq.h(20): warning C4820: 'PyStructSequence_Desc': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'PyStructSequence_Desc::n_in_sequence'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(19): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(23): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(33): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(40): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(49): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(54): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(66): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\modsupport.h(97): warning C4820: '_PyArg_Parser': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_PyArg_Parser::max'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\code.h(32): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::co_firstlineno'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\code.h(69): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '3' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::co_opcache_size'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\import.h(138): warning C4820: '_frozen': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_frozen::size'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/abstract.h(77): warning C4365: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'Py_ssize_t', signed/unsigned mismatch
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(73): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_dev'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(75): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '2' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_mode'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(79): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_rdev'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(82): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_atime_nsec'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(84): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_mtime_nsec'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(88): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_reparse_tag'
  pdftotext.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pdftotext
  Running setup.py clean for pdftotext
Failed to build pdftotext
Installing collected packages: pdftotext
    Running setup.py install for pdftotext ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\humma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\humma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\humma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wp1uwcr6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include\pdftotext'
         cwd: C:\Users\humma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\pdftotext\
    Complete output (69 lines):
    WARNING: pkg-config not found--guessing at poppler version.
             If the build fails, install pkg-config and try again.
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pdftotext' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=1 -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tppdftotext.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pdftotext.obj -Wall
    pdftotext.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(49): warning C4820: '_finddata32i64_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_finddata32i64_t::name'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(54): warning C4820: '_finddata64i32_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_finddata64i32_t::attrib'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(64): warning C4820: '__finddata64_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '__finddata64_t::attrib'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_io.h(69): warning C4820: '__finddata64_t': '4' bytes padding added after data member '__finddata64_t::name'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\time.h(36): warning C4820: '_timespec64': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_timespec64::tv_nsec'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\time.h(43): warning C4820: 'timespec': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'timespec::tv_nsec'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\object.h(182): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::slot'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\object.h(190): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::flags'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(212): warning C4820: '_typeobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_typeobject::tp_flags'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(256): warning C4820: '_typeobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_typeobject::tp_version_tag'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\bytearrayobject.h(30): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ob_exports'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\bytesobject.h(41): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ob_sval'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\bytesobject.h(165): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::small_buffer'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(221): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::state'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(625): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '2' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::readonly'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\longintrepr.h(88): warning C4820: '_longobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_longobject::ob_digit'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\memoryobject.h(45): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::flags'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\memoryobject.h(62): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::flags'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\methodobject.h(56): warning C4820: 'PyMethodDef': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'PyMethodDef::ml_flags'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\moduleobject.h(63): warning C4820: 'PyModuleDef_Slot': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'PyModuleDef_Slot::slot'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(16): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::_type'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(19): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::exitcode'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(202): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::parse_argv'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(357): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::legacy_windows_stdio'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(367): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::pathconfig_warnings'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(374): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::module_search_paths_set'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/initconfig.h(393): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::skip_source_first_line'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(65): warning C4820: '_ts': '2' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::recursion_critical'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(73): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::use_tracing'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(96): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::gilstate_counter'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pystate.h(130): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_ts::coroutine_origin_tracking_depth'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(35): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::gi_running'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(55): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::cr_running'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(72): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ag_running'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\genobject.h(85): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::ag_running_async'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\descrobject.h(29): warning C4820: 'wrapperbase': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'wrapperbase::offset'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\descrobject.h(33): warning C4820: 'wrapperbase': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'wrapperbase::flags'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\structseq.h(20): warning C4820: 'PyStructSequence_Desc': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'PyStructSequence_Desc::n_in_sequence'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(19): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(23): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(33): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(40): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(49): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(54): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(66): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::suppress_context'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\modsupport.h(97): warning C4820: '_PyArg_Parser': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_PyArg_Parser::max'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\code.h(32): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::co_firstlineno'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\code.h(69): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '3' bytes padding added after data member '<unnamed-tag>::co_opcache_size'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\import.h(138): warning C4820: '_frozen': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_frozen::size'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\cpython/abstract.h(77): warning C4365: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'Py_ssize_t', signed/unsigned mismatch
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(73): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_dev'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(75): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '2' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_mode'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(79): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_rdev'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(82): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_atime_nsec'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(84): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_mtime_nsec'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include\fileutils.h(88): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_Py_stat_struct::st_reparse_tag'
    pdftotext.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\humma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\humma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zo6vfv8o\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\humma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wp1uwcr6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include\pdftotext' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda install -c conda-forge poppler`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but could you tell me if I need to pre-install anything for using `Conda`? I'm not really aware of this package manager. I have only used `pip`

Comment: You need to download Conda from https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/ 
in the installations make sure you add conda to path and then you will be able to install your package